# Max Size of a file that can be compressed into one CAB file using Microsoft Dlls

Tags: c#, windows, filesystems, windows-server, cab

I am using ["Microsoft Deployment Compression Cab 1.0.0"](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MSFTCompressionCab/) nuget package in my C# code to compress one file into one Cab file (need to maintain 1 to 1 ratio), to quote the parent source of this package:

> This package contains Microsoft Dlls that make it easier to work with cabinet files (.cab) or some of their derivatives from .net code.

My question is regarding the max file size that will be supported by microsoft dlls for compression if the code is running over Windows Server 2010 and onwards?

P.S. Some sources like [this](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/07b6ff1d-1bfc-4de2-984a-21379861ef2f/maximum-size-of-cab-file?forum=netfxcompact) suggest that it's 2GB but that used to be the case in FAT days. Am I right in assuming that it must be greater than 2GB now and will only be limited by the current file system's maximum file size?

Comment: If you need to know then you are doing it wrong.  An executable file cannot be that big.  It must be able to be mapped into memory, an MMF can never be larger than 4GB.  Most toolchains will keel over and die before it gets to 2GB, assuming the programmer doesn't die from boredom or sword stabs first.

Comment: @HansPassant Lol, I agree with you about the max size and sword stabs. just to put it clearly on record, the microsoft compression dlls do not put any size constraints from their end it's the "mapping back to memory" that decides what can and should be the max size of file being compressed right?